# Changing css via JavaScript conditional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to modify the css of a class depending on the URL. Here is the currently non-working code:

JS:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[ 
if (location.pathname == "/SearchResults.asp" 
|| location.pathname.indexOf("-s/") != -1 
|| location.pathname.indexOf("_s/") != -1) 
$('.colors_productname span').css("background-color", "#F7F7F7");
//]]> 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class=
    "productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Cracked Pepper"><span itemprop=
    'name'>Cracked Pepper</span></a><br />
    <div>
    <div>
      <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class=
      "PageText_L483n">$11.00</span></font></b>
    </div>
    <img src="#" /></div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. I can't change the HTML, it is automatically generated
2. The URL of the HTML includes "/Meats-s/", so it should be targeted by the second if conditional.
3. I can edit it with the same css selector (.colors_productname span) in a normal .css file, but this does not work.

Comment: Did you put your JavaScript in a tag at the bottom of your `body`  below your jQuery? The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: @PHPglue: what does "not supported in HTML5" mean? "red".fontcolor("red") still shows as red when i use an HTML5 doctype, despite the invalid color spec and terrible semantics... i thought all non-spec'd tags mean "SPAN" in HTML5.

Comment: See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encase your code in `DOM Ready handler`

```
$(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Encasing your code in the above handler will make sure you code runs only after the elements are available in the DOM.

And it is always faster to use `===` instead of `==` .

Also you seem to be using the `window.location` multiple times. Consider caching it.

```
$(function() {
   var loc = location.pathname;
   if (loc === "/SearchResults.asp" || loc.indexOf("-s/") !== -1
                                    || loc.indexOf("_s/") !== -1
   $('.colors_productname span').css("background-color", "#F7F7F7");
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works. I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!